# Tidyverse: filtering n largest groups in grouped dataframe

Tags: r, dplyr, top-n

I want to filter the n largest groups based on count, and then do some calculations on the filtered dataframe

Here is some data

```
Brand <- c("A","B","C","A","A","B","A","A","B","C")
Category <- c(1,2,1,1,2,1,2,1,2,1)
Clicks <- c(10,11,12,13,14,15,14,13,12,11)
df <- data.frame(Brand,Category,Clicks)

|Brand | Category| Clicks|
|:-----|--------:|------:|
|A     |        1|     10|
|B     |        2|     11|
|C     |        1|     12|
|A     |        1|     13|
|A     |        2|     14|
|B     |        1|     15|
|A     |        2|     14|
|A     |        1|     13|
|B     |        2|     12|
|C     |        1|     11|
```

This is my expected output. I want to filter out the two largest brands by count and then find the mean clicks in each brand / category combination

```
|Brand | Category| mean_clicks|
|:-----|--------:|-----------:|
|A     |        1|        12.0|
|A     |        2|        14.0|
|B     |        1|        15.0|
|B     |        2|        11.5|
```

Which I thought could be achieved with code like this (but can't)

```
df %>%
  group_by(Brand, Category) %>%
  top_n(2, Brand) %>% # Largest 2 brands by count
  summarise(mean_clicks = mean(Clicks))
```

EDIT: the ideal answer should be able to be used on database tables as well as local tables

Comment: You might want to precise what DBMS you intend to use, not all of them support window functions and `dbplyr` might need them for some of its translations. I believe @Ronak's answer should work on a DB where window functions are supported but fail for others because of `add_count`, a fix would be to group and count in a subquery, join it to the original and proceed.

Comment: actually @Paul's solution might work right away as it seems to do just that

Answer (score 7, accepted):

Another `dplyr` solution using a `join` to filter the data frame:

```
library(dplyr)

df %>%
  group_by(Brand) %>%
  summarise(n = n()) %>%
  top_n(2) %>% # select top 2
  left_join(df, by = "Brand") %>% # filters out top 2 Brands
  group_by(Brand, Category) %>%
  summarise(mean_clicks = mean(Clicks))

# # A tibble: 4 x 3
# # Groups:   Brand [?]
#   Brand Category mean_clicks
#   <fct>    <dbl>       <dbl>
# 1 A            1        12  
# 2 A            2        14  
# 3 B            1        15  
# 4 B            2        11.5
```

Comment: +1 because even if it's longer than some, I believe it's the only solution that will work in all DBMS supported by `dbplyr`. `arrange(desc(n)) %>%
  head(2)` could be replaced by using `top_n`

Answer (score 4):

A different `dplyr` solution:

```
df %>%
  group_by(Brand) %>%
  mutate(n = n()) %>%
  ungroup() %>%
  mutate(rank = dense_rank(desc(n))) %>%
  filter(rank == 1 | rank == 2) %>%
  group_by(Brand, Category) %>%
  summarise(mean_clicks = mean(Clicks))

# A tibble: 4 x 3
# Groups:   Brand [?]
  Brand Category mean_clicks
  <fct>    <dbl>       <dbl>
1 A           1.        12.0
2 A           2.        14.0
3 B           1.        15.0
4 B           2.        11.5
```

Or a simplified version (based on suggestions from @camille):

```
df %>%
  group_by(Brand) %>%
  mutate(n = n()) %>%
  ungroup() %>%
  filter(dense_rank(desc(n)) < 3) %>%
  group_by(Brand, Category) %>%
  summarise(mean_clicks = mean(Clicks))
```

Comment: The only improvement I'd suggest on this is that since you want the first 2 ranks, instead of `rank == 1 | rank == 2`, you could make it cleaner with `rank <= 2` or `rank < 3`. That way, you can also easily skip the `mutate` line and create a rank inside the `filter` call

Answer (score 2):

**EDIT**

Based on updated question, we can add a count column first, filter only top `n` group counts, then `group_by` `Brand` and `Category` to find the `mean` for each group.

```
df %>%
  add_count(Brand, sort = TRUE) %>%
  filter(n %in% head(unique(n), 2)) %>%
  group_by(Brand, Category) %>%
  summarise(mean_clicks = mean(Clicks))


#   Brand Category mean_clicks
#   <fct>    <dbl>       <dbl>
#1 A            1        12  
#2 A            2        14  
#3 B            1        15  
#4 B            2        11.5
```

**Original Answer**

We can `group_by` `Brand` and do all the calculations by group and then filter top groups by `top_n`

```
library(dplyr)
df %>%
  group_by(Brand) %>%
  summarise(n = n(), 
            mean = mean(Clicks)) %>%
  top_n(2, n) %>%
  select(-n)

#  Brand  mean
#  <fct> <dbl>
#1  A      12.8
#2  B      12.7
```

Comment: Thank you for your answer Ronak, but I can see a situation where this will not work. I will edit my question

Comment: using `filter(n %in% head(unique(n), 2))` is a very clever idea. But I cant help but thinking there must be a faster / more elegant solution?

Comment: @Shinobi_Atobe I agree. Even I have a feeling that there should be something better, can't think of anything right now though.

Comment: If you filter based on `dense_rank` ([as @tmfmnk did](https://stackoverflow.com/a/52532885/1851712)), you can skip the sorting in `add_count` and use `df %>% add_count(Brand) %>% filter(dense_rank(desc(n)) %in% 1:2)`. Have no clue if this is 'faster / more elegant'..;)

Comment: @Henrik yes.definitely but it does not reduce any of the step. Just replaces one with another.

Answer (score 0):

A [data.table](/questions/tagged/data.table) idea is to get the counts grouped by `Brands` and filter the top two (after ordering in descending order). Then we merge with the original data frame and find the mean grouped by `(Brand, Category)`

```
library(data.table)

#Convert to data.table
dt1 <- setDT(df)

dt1[dt1[, .(cnt = .N), by = Brand][
             order(cnt, decreasing = TRUE), .SD[1:2]][,cnt := NULL], 
                   on = 'Brand'][, .(means = mean(Clicks)), by = .(Brand, Category)][]
```

which gives,

> ```
>    Brand Category means
> 1:     A        1  12.0
> 2:     A        2  14.0
> 3:     B        2  11.5
> 4:     B        1  15.0
> ```

Answer (score 0):

How about this approach, using `table`, from base R -

```
df %>%
  filter(Brand %in% names(tail(sort(table(Brand)), 2))) %>%
  group_by(Brand, Category) %>%
  summarise(mean_clicks = mean(Clicks))

# A tibble: 4 x 3
# Groups:   Brand [?]
  Brand Category mean_clicks
  <chr>    <dbl>       <dbl>
1 A         1.00        12.0
2 A         2.00        14.0
3 B         1.00        15.0
4 B         2.00        11.5
```

Comment: or `names(tail(sort(table(x)),2))` to be a bit more compact, a function `is_in_top_group <- function(x,n) x %in% names(tail(sort(table(x)),n))` would make it convenient to reuse.

Comment: @Moody_Mudskipper Thanks! don't know how I missed that. Edited my answer.

Answer (score 0):

## Slightly different than above. Just because I don't like to use join with large datasets. Some people might not like that I make and remove a small dataframe, sorry :(

```
df %>% count(Brand) %>% top_n(2,n) -> Top2
df %>% group_by(Brand, Category) %>% 
filter(Brand %in% Top2$Brand) %>% 
summarise(mean_clicks = mean(Clicks))
remove(Top2)
```